# Incomplete type error when instantiating class

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

I have a vertex class that has an id and adjacency list as private members. The adjacency list is stored as a map. When I instantiate an object of this class I want to create an empty map. I am switching over from python to C++ and its proving harder than I thought. Here's the code for the class:

```
#include "vertex.h"

class Vertex {
    char _id;
    std::map<char, int> _adjList;

public:
    void addNeighbor(Vertex, char neighbor, int weight);
    std::vector<char> getConnections(Vertex);
    char getId();
    int getWeight(Vertex, char neighbor);
    Vertex(char);
};

Vertex::Vertex(char id){
    std::map<char, int> adjList;
    _adjList = adjList;
    _id = id;

}

void Vertex::addNeighbor(Vertex v, char neighbor, int weight){
    v._adjList.insert(std::map<char, int>::value_type(neighbor, weight));
}

std::vector<char> Vertex::getConnections(Vertex v){
    std::vector<char> ids;
    for(std::map<char,int>::iterator it = v._adjList.begin(); it != v._adjList.end(); ++it) {
        ids.push_back(it->first);
    };
    return ids;
}

char Vertex::getId(){
    return _id;
}

int Vertex::getWeight(Vertex v, char neighbor){
    return v._adjList[neighbor];
}
```

Now when I instantiate this in main

```
Vertex V('a');
```

The compiler throws an error that the variable has incomplete type Vertex. Any help is greatly appreciated. Basically I want to construct an object with an id and empty map that will hold the id and path weight to the adjacent node. I am doing this for learning purposes

My vertex.h has:

```
#ifndef __graphs__vertex__
#define __graphs__vertex__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class Vertex;

#endif
```

and then in my main I include vertex.h

Comment: What does your source file with `main` in it include?

Comment: #include <iostream> and #include "vertex.h"

Comment: What has this question to do with `std::map`?

Comment: "incomplete type" means that the compiler has not seen the definition of `Vertex`.  How do you have things divided into header and source?

Comment: Did you include `<map>` and `<vector>`?

Comment: `std::map<char, int> adjList; _adjList = adjList;` is unnecessary, the `map` will be default constructed in any case. `vertex.h` needs to contain the definition of the `Vertex` class, not just a declaration, otherwise how is the compiler supposed to instantiate it within `main`? Please consider reading a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/241631).

Comment: Please read a basic book; or just *any* source code of a real C++ project, to learn how to divide code into files.

Comment: @KerrekSB This is part of my learning process. I am reading a book and coding alongside it which helps me learn better. A site like this helps people like me to seek help if I am stuck.

Comment: @Fizi: No, not really. Books, tutorials, lecture notes and reading existing code help people like you. This site helps people who can *not* be helped easily by means of existing literature, search engines or examples, and who need human intervention.

Comment: @KerrekSB I get your point. To be honest I have looked at the tutorials online and reading essential C++ but Included the definition in the cpp file and my line of thinking didn't really see it as the problem. Only then I asked the question. But I'll refrain from asking stupid questions in future

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration/1410632#1410632

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration/4757718?s=12|0.3230#4757718

Comment: Feel free to ask stupid questions. Just take care not to ask questions, stupid or otherwise, that are already answered at length. Odds are you'll have to ask a few anyway simply because you can't google up an answer if you don't know the the right terms.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of Vertex should be in header, not in cpp:

I fixed declaration of method to add `const` and remove parameter Vertax as you should use `this` value.

```
#ifndef graphs_vertex_h
#define graphs_vertex_h

#include <map>
#include <vector>

class Vertex {
    char _id;
    std::map<char, int> _adjList;

public:
    explicit Vertex(char);

    void addNeighbor(char neighbor, int weight);
    std::vector<char> getConnections();
    char getId() const;
    int getWeight(char neighbor) const;
};

#endif
```